# $http calls with angular routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just setup routes in my angular app. The first view, `List` makes an http call to get a list of presentations

```
function ListController($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.error            = null;
    $scope.presentations    = null;
    $scope.requesting       = true;
    $scope.currentTitle     = '-1';
    $data = {
        'type' : 'presentations'
    };

    $http.post('resources/request.php', $data, {timeout:20000})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {
            $scope.requesting   = false;
            $scope.presentations    = data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {
            $scope.requesting   = false;
            log(status + ', data:" ' + data + '"');
        }
      }
    );
}
```

My route is

```
angular.module('main',[]).
  config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {controller:ListController, templateUrl:'resources/views/list.html'}).
      when('/view/:id', {controller:VforumController, templateUrl:'resources/views/vforum.html'}).
      otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
  });
```

the problem I have is when I go to `#/view/:id` and then back to `/` the `$http` call gets called again. How can I make it so it only loads the first time going into the app and reference the same data that was loaded the first time?

I attempted to create a variable outside of angular and set it equal to the data loaded the first time. Then, in the `ListController` basically did a `if data is null, do the $http call else set $scope.data = data` but that didn't work. The list view was just blank. `$scope.data` is what builds my list.

Comment: Did you try passing `$route` to your controller and checking the [`$routeParams`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeParams) before the `$http.post()`? Worth a shot.

Comment: I've never used `$routeParams` before..well, `$routes` in general. This is my first time. I'll look into this, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a service, which in angular is a singleton:

```js
.factory( 'myDataService', function ( $http ) {
  var promise;

  return function ( $data ) {
    if ( ! angular.isDefined( promise ) ) {
      promise = $http.post('resources/request.php', $data, {timeout:20000});
    }

    return promise;
  }
});
```

And now you can simply replace the call to `$http` with a call to your service:

```js
function ListController( $scope, myDataService )
{
  // ...

  myDataService( $data ).then( function success( response ) {
    $scope.requesting = false;
    $scope.presentations = response.data;
  }, function error( response ) {
    $scope.requesting = false;
    log(status + ', data:" ' + response.data + '"');
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't think I am doing this correct. I am getting `$data` is not defined. Again, haven't used factories/services before: http://pastie.org/7084834 what is wrong here? How do I pass `$data` to the service?

Comment: That depends on whether it's static. Since you defined it statically here, you can just place it statically in the service. If you want to have it dynamic, then your factory can return a function instead. I'll  update the answer for the latter case.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Is `var promise` what the service is checking? I am not sure what is making it so the app doesn't invoke the $http call twice. In other words, does `promise` containt my loaded data?

Comment: No, `promise` is a [promise](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q). :-) A promise provides an API for working with data that is generated asynchronously. `$http` returns one, which we store the first time the function returned from the service is called. Each subsequent time, that `promise` has already been defined, so we just return the existing one. Inside the promise chain is your data; you must *always* access the data from within `then` blocks because your code doesn't know if the data has been loaded yet. Whether it takes 7 ms or 7 sec won't matter and you don't need to account for it.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. This is awesome. I am loving angular the more I use it, thank you!